# An action failed. No dependent actions succeeded - Missing or Mismatched field definition

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

This flow has been working for over a year and has just stopped working this past week.

This is a simple flow of changing an item's property in an SPO library then moving to another folder if a given property is true. The output says something about the Sign-Off Status column but this column is not being used in the source location. The column is present in the list but it's hidden and there is no data in the field. There are plenty of other columns not being used in the source library that are different than the destination.

*Missing or mismatched field definition on the destination list for source field 'Sign_x002d_off_x0020_status' type 'Text'. Source site template id 'SitePagePublishing', target site template id 'SitePagePublishing'.*

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your destination library does not have the `Sign-Off Status` column. If this flow has been previously working and has only just recently stopped, my guess is that someone has [enabled Approvals](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/power-apps-power-automate/configure-flow-options-sharepoint-library/m-p/307946) on the source library. Doing this adds the Sign-Off Status column.

The easiest way to resolve this would be to enable Approvals on the destination library or manually create a text column called `Sign-Off Status`.

The opposite approach would be to delete the Sign-Off Status column from the source library, but that has the potential to cause issues for something else.

Comment: I understand that the source and destination have different columns, the source has at least 12 columns that the destination doesn't have.  Why is this one column an issue? Approvals have been enabled on the source longer than the destination has existed.

Comment: I added a column with the same name but that didn't work. I had to select Automate > Request Sign Off to resolve the issue. The actual column is Sign_x002d_off_x0020_status as indicated in my browser's address bar when I go to edit the column. So, thanks for the right answer.... even though I don't like it and it doesn't make sense.